# feedback on HDD speeds for a HP Proliant ML110 Gen10 server

Tags: virtual-machines, domain-controller, hp-proliant, raid10

I have a RAID 1+0 array in a HP Proliant ML110 Gen10 server with 4 x 7200RPM 2.5" 6Gbps SATA drives. The power management is set to Static High Performance Mode.

I ran a CrystalDiskMark benchmark and here's what I got.
[image]

The Hyper-V is running "on metal" whereas the DC is in a VM on the Hyper-V. The numbers look kinda on the low end for a RAID 1+0 config. Is there anything I can do to improve the performance?

Please let me know if I'm missing any pertinent information.

TIA

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a forum for low/dead end hardware.

Comment: It's still a real server.

Comment: What's the storage controller? The P408i-p (*with* battery) runs quite decently for its class. The onboard S100i sucks extremely and the E208i isn't really worth its money either when writing. The 7.2k drives are rather low end though, so don't expect miracles.

Comment: It is using the onboard controller, which is likely a bottleneck like you suggest. Thanks the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to get better speeds out of those drives without a RAID cache or a higher-end standalone SmartArray controller.